# My CSS is a bit rusty

Tags: css

Below is my CSS script for a website I'm making:

```
@charset "utf-8";
/* CSS Document */
body{background-color:#3b5998; font-family:Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif; color:red;}
link{color:red}
visited{color:purple}
hover{color:pink}
active{color:black}
```

Here's the HTML File

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>My Website</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mystyle.css">
</head>

<body>
<table width="115" height="484" border="5">
  <tr>
    <td width="97"><a href="home.html" target="mainFrame">Home</a></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><a href="flashchart.html" target="mainFrame">Flash</a></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><a href="browsertest.html" target="mainFrame">Browser Test</a></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Upload</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Download</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Exit</td>
  </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

It doesn't seem to be working...
What's wrong?

Comment: What have you tried? Have you toyed around with it on [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)? Have you looked at the debugger for your broswer to see how it's being parsed or if there are parsing errors? (You're missing most of your semicolons!) What specifically isn't working?

Comment: I'm going to guess the body style works, but the link ones don't...

Comment: Yeah, the body is working but the links aren't, because I'm not sure how to format the link attributes in the CSS file

Comment: `a:link`, `a:hover`, etc. -- did you consider reading a tutorial?

Answer (score 1):

I think you mean this:

```
body{background-color:#3b5998; font-family:Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif; color:red;}

a{color:red;}

a:visited{color:purple;}

a:hover{color:pink;}

a:active{color:black;}
```

Comment: No, I wanted to be able to import the CSS and have it apply to everything instead of having to add a tag to everything

Comment: link, visited, hover and active are all selectors. They are active when the tag is in a certain state. They don't work if you don't say which tag they belong to (an anchor, I assume in this case). If you meant to use them as a class or an id, you should write '#visited' for an id or '.visited' for a class.

Comment: @SimonVerbeke 's answer works, add in the "a" (anchor / link) tags

Answer (score -1):

Add the missing semicolons and the tags

```
body{background-color:#3b5998; font-family:Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif; color:red;}

a:link{color:red;}

a:visited{color:purple;}

a:hover{color:pink;}

a:active{color:black;}
```

Comment: Ah, I placed the semicolons outside the brackets

Comment: Still doesn't work

Comment: Could you please post the HTML file as well?

Comment: @hanxue I edited the original question to include the HTML